# choice of words: minimized to - limited to

Tags: word-choice

> The company's first products were minimized to hats and scarfs only, but soon after other accessories were added to the range of products.

Is that sentence correct? I think it should rather be:

> At first the company's assortment was limited to scarfs and hats, but other accessories were added to its range soon after.

Comment: You are right. 'Minimized' has the sense of 'deliberately made as small as possible', which is not appropriate in this context.

Comment: I doubt that minimise + to + NP is grammatical.

Comment: They do not mean the same. Both *minimized* and *limited* are perfect right and have their uses. Think again.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What could be wrong with *minimise* + *to* + NP?  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=minimized+to+_NOUN_&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cminimized%20to%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Kris There are modern examples such as 'minimised to the taskbar' using a quasi-directional to-phrase, but I haven't found any examples using OP's 'limited / restricted / confined' [to a less-than-the-maximum-possible range etc] sense. Have you? I can't get to the examples from Ngrams nowadays.

Comment: There are only just over 5000 Google hits for 'were minimised to'. Most of these are the 'in order to' sense, some are of the forms 'were minimised to those least able to pay', 'were minimised to the best possible degree', etc,  and the few that remain seem strange 'were minimised to a minimal amount' or computer-related directionals (were minimised to the tray).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Minimized to the taskbar/ tray" use *to* in the directional sense as you already noted, and so are not relevant.

Answer (score -1):

**Limited** or confined.

The company's first products were **limited** to hats and scarfs only, but soon after other accessories were added to the range of products.

Comment: Why not *minimized*?

Comment: Hi @Kris, as explained above by Kate B.  Also note, noun phrase or nominal phrase (abbreviated NP) is a phrase which has a noun (or indefinite pronoun) as its head, or which performs the same grammatical function as such a phrase, ref https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase

Comment: What about that?